# Is this the answer to Bitcoin's massive energy consumption issues?

Tags: mining-hardware, mining-profitability, mining-theory, miner-configuration, energy-consumption

In today’s world carbon footprint and efficiency matter.

A lot of real world resources are burned away and a massive amount of computing power and electricity is spent on the bitcoin ledger to verify blocks.

It is necessary but it could be done better and efficiently. [Here is my solution using renewable energy with the latest technology.](https://youtu.be/NyzfB9-ug4g)

As I move forward with this project what do you foresee being the largest obstacles? What are any questions that come to mind?

Can you offer any guidance in support of what we are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably make more money selling the energy you farm than you can mining BTC with it.

Comment: On the economic end of the project the plan is to only sell the acquired assets needed to maintain operations and hold all others. Bitcoin itself would be sold into a $40,000 - $110,000 price range. Much more profitable than selling energy unless Bitcoin itself does not reach our projections.

Comment: If that's your plan, buy Bitcoin. Much more profitable than solar energy farming.

Comment: Then why are operations spending hundreds of millions of dollars on new plants and chip technology RnD instead of simply buying bitcoin? Mining is cheaper than buying in the long run. Even with increasing difficulty. Even with electricity. In the long run solar is cheaper than electricity. Of course not up front but once you recoup your equipment investment.

Comment: Mining is extremely competitive. People don't leave free money on the table. Miners buy state of the art equipment that becomes obsolete in 6 months or less. They pay for the cheapest electricity on the planet. They /immediately/ sell their coins to pay for these costs. They *don't* hold onto x percent in the dream that it will go to the moon and they can turn a profit.

Thinking you can mine profitably with solar is a fantasy at best or at worst a con you're actively perpetrating on hapless investors in your dumb project.